# Как получить уникальные значения словаря через set?

Tags: python, словари, jupyter-notebook, set

У меня есть код:

```
ids = {"user1": (213, 213, 213, 15, 213),
"user2": (54, 54, 119, 119, 119),
"user3": (213, 98, 98, 35)}
set_of_ids = []
for value in ids.values():
    set_of_ids.extend(value)
    print("Уникальные гео-метки пользователей", set(set_of_ids))
```

Результат выходит:

```
Уникальные гео-метки пользователей {213, 15}
Уникальные гео-метки пользователей {119, 213, 54, 15}
Уникальные гео-метки пользователей {98, 35, 15, 213, 54, 119}
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы осталась последняя строчка, уникальные метки всех пользователей. А у меня выходит сперва вывод по каждому пользователю и отдельно общий список.

Comment: вынесите `print` за цикл ;)

Comment: спасибо) не думала, что надо просто добавить пустую строку)

Comment: да, я убрала, все работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = set()
_ = [res.update(x) for x in ids.values()]
print(f"Уникальные гео-метки пользователей: {res}")
```

вывод:

```
Уникальные гео-метки пользователей: {98, 35, 15, 213, 54, 119}
```

**UPD:** более оптимальный вариант решения (без циклов):

```
res = set(sum(ids.values(), tuple()))
```

Comment: я взяла первый вариант, вынесла print за цикл)

Comment: без цикла хорошо, но по условию задачи нужно пользоваться циклом)

Comment: @Alina, попробуйте приятно удивить преподавателя! :-D Будь я преподом, я бы оценил ;)

Comment: как-нибудь в следующий раз)

Comment: в первом вашем варианте можно даже не сохранять полученный список никуда - написать просто `[res.update(x) for x in ids.values()]`

Comment: @n1tr0xs, так он вернёт None’s, а это некрасиво)